# Django _id in FK Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm doing an API from a existing database (which means it's not an option to change de DB schema) with Django and rest_framework. I have 2 tables, Foos and Bars.

```
foo_id
1
2
```

```
bar_id | foo_id (FK)
1      |1
2      |2
```

Bars model:
`foo = models.ForeignKey('Foos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`
The Django Model changes de 'foo_id' FK into 'foo' only. There is a way to keep the FK with the '_id' suffix?

Comment: The database column uses the name of the field with an `_id` suffix, so this will work with this database schema.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest specifying the field you want to use as a FK (foos_id in your case).

```
models.ForeignKey(
    Foos,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    to_field='id'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed using:
`foo_id = models.ForeignKey('Foos', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='foo_id')`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the serializer with:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='foo')

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ['foo_id']
```

or even simply:

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ['foo_id']
```

Giving the model field the name `foo_id` however makes *no* sense: if you access `bar_object.foo`, you get a `Foo` object, not the id of a `Foo` object, so naming it `foo_id` is *misleading*.